# Count same value at dictionary array, when its added in to table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with tables and I create table from JS file, after tapping button.

When i tap button, it's get data from dictionary and add, in to table.

So i have some position, if i add one position in to table, and when i tap seccond time i recived same position, its add value +1 in to counter.

```js
var users = [{
  name: "Name1",
  id: "6183",
  position: "Shift Leader",
  cardId: "0"
}, {
  name: "Name2",
  id: "6686",
  position: "Master",
  cardId: "1"
}, {
  name: "Name3",
  id: "10526",
  position: "Operator",
  cardId: "2"
}, {
  name: "Name4",
  id: "10527",
  position: "Operator",
  cardId: "3"
}, {
  name: "Name5",
  id: "10433",
  position: "Qualiti inspector",
  cardId: "4"
}];

$('#plus-button').on('click', function() {
  filterUsers(users)
});

function filterUsers(userData) {
  var msg = window.prompt("Scan operato ID card", "");
  $.each(userData, function(i, data) {
    if (msg === data.cardId) {
      groupData(data);
    }
  });
}

function groupData(data) {
  var count = 0;

  $('.positionUsers').show();
  $(".positionUsers > tbody").append('<tr class="add"><td>' + data.position + '</td><td>' + count + '</td></tr>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plus-button">
  <p class="plus">+</p>
</button>
<table class="positionUsers hiden">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Currently working at this station:
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

So if I have after addind in table **"Operator" and i add one more operator**, it's count +1.

And if I add the **same user position**, then it's not allow to add to table.

So in the end, when I click **PLUS** it's check all data on the table, if user position are already in the table it's added to counter +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all you should have a variable where you need to store your counters. There are 2 different ways. You can extend you initial users array with property count:0, or you can create another array with this property. After that I would like to mention that you have to empty your table each time you want to update values. Please try my working example:

```js
var users = [{
  name: "Name1",
  id: "6183",
  position: "Shift Leader",
  cardId: "0"
}, {
  name: "Name2",
  id: "6686",
  position: "Master",
  cardId: "1"
}, {
  name: "Name3",
  id: "10526",
  position: "Operator",
  cardId: "2"
}, {
  name: "Name4",
  id: "10527",
  position: "Operator",
  cardId: "3"
}, {
  name: "Name5",
  id: "10433",
  position: "Qualiti inspector",
  cardId: "4"
}];

var usersCount = users.reduce((accumulator, c) => {
 var a = accumulator.filter(user => user.position === c.position);
 if(a.length > 0){
  a[0].cardIds.push(c.cardId);
 }else{
  accumulator.push({position: c.position, cardIds: [c.cardId], count: 0});
 }
 
 return accumulator;
}, []);
 
$('#plus-button').on('click', function() {
  const cardId = window.prompt("Scan operato ID card", "");
 const filteredUsers = usersCount.filter(user => user.cardIds.indexOf(cardId) !== -1);
 
 if(filteredUsers.length > 0){
  filteredUsers[0].count++;
  $(".positionUsers > tbody").empty();
  usersCount.filter(user => user.count > 0).forEach(user => {
   $(".positionUsers > tbody").append('<tr class="add"><td>' + user.position + '</td><td>' + user.count + '</td></tr>');
  });
  $('.positionUsers').show();
 }else{
 alert('This card id does not exists')
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="plus-button">
  <p class="plus">+</p>
</button>
<table class="positionUsers hiden">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">
        Currently working at this station:
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's good, but for **name: "Name3" and name: "Name4"** we have same position, and this must not add additionad table row, just increace counter

Comment: I've updated my answer, now is working pretty well according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right you could remember the ids you already typed an save them in an array like so:

```
var users = [{
  name: "Name1",
  id: "6183",
  position: "Shift Leader",
  cardId: "0"
}, {
  name: "Name2",
  id: "6686",
  position: "Master",
  cardId: "1"
}, {
  name: "Name3",
  id: "10526",
  position: "Operator",
  cardId: "2"
}, {
  name: "Name4",
  id: "10527",
  position: "Operator",
  cardId: "3"
}, {
  name: "Name5",
  id: "10433",
  position: "Qualiti inspector",
  cardId: "4"
}];

var usedIds = [];

$('#plus-button').on('click', function() {
  filterUsers(users)
});

function filterUsers(userData) {
  var msg = window.prompt("Scan operato ID card", "");
  $.each(userData, function(i, data) {
    if (msg === data.cardId && usedIds.indexOf(msg) < 0) {
      usedIds.push(msg);
      groupData(data);
    } else if (msg === data.cardId) {
      var element = document.getElementById(data.position);
      var positionCount = parseInt(element.innerHTML);
      element.innerHTML = positionCount+1;
    }
  });
}

function groupData(data) {
  var count = 0;

  $('.positionUsers').show();
  $(".positionUsers > tbody").append('<tr class="add"><td>' + data.position + '</td><td id="'+data.position+'">' + count + '</td></tr>');
}
```

If you want to increase the counter you should also use ids or classes to identify the count `<td>` from each row. Then you can count up the counter by selecting the element. I edited my comment now you can count up if the row exists.